# Data interpretation problem

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

[image]

> Approximately what is the minimum amount of caffeine, in milligrams,
>   consumed per day by a person who daily drinks two 10-ounce mugs of
>   percolated coffee and one 12-ounce cup of a caffeinated soft drink?

***The answer is given:***

> According to the bar graph, the minimum amount of caffeine in a
>   5-ounce cup of percolated coffee is **approximately 40 milligrams.**
>   Therefore, the minimum amount of caffeine in two 10-ounce cups of
>   percolated coffee, which is the same as the minimum amount of caffeine
>   in four 5-ounce cups, **is approximately (40)(4),** or 160 milligrams. The
>   minimum amount of caffeine in a 12-ounce caffeinated soft drink is
>   approximately 30 milligrams. So, the minimum amount of caffeine in two
>   10-ounce mugs of percolated coffee and one 12-ounce caffeinated soft
>   drink is approximately 160 + 30, or 190 milligrams.

**How they have got the percolated coffee   approximately 40 milligrams? May be i am confused with the ounce measuring.**

Comment: The lower endpoint of the variation of caffeine for percolated coffee is more than 25 milligrams, but a little less than 50. So approximately 40.

Comment: From the graph, is seems slightly on the right of $37.5$ which is the average between $25$ and $50$. So, $40$ seems to be a good reading.

Answer (score 1):

They simply read the left endpoint of the bar and see it's a bit below $50$ so they name it $40$
With pixel by pixel zooming you can see that the exact reading would be $\frac{1125}{29}\approx38.7...$ but for these purposes the $1.3$ error dosen't really make any difference.

I think the reason that you posted this is when you look at the graph, it actually dosen't look like it goes down to $40$ but this is all visual things.